# No Assets in Phonegap

Tags: cordova

I was following a tutorial on how to make my first app on phonegap so I typed this into my command

```
C:\Users\KTR\Desktop\phonegap\lib\android\bin>create C:\Users\KTR\Desktop\firsta
pp com.example.firstapp firstapp
Creating new android project...
Copying template files...
Copying js, jar & config.xml files...
Copying cordova command tools...
Updating AndroidManifest.xml and Main Activity...
```

But when I imported the folder that was created into my eclipse, there was no 'assets/www' folder where the html/css file is supposed to be

This is an picture of what the folder currently looks like on elipse

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXOB1.jpg

Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 2):

To show `assets/www` or `res/xml/config.xml`, go to:
    Project -> Properties -> Resource -> Resource Filters
And delete the exclusion filter.